# Seleccionar una sola vez los valores de una fila cuando cierto valor de una columna está repetido

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta tabla y necesito seleccionar una sola vez ciertas filas, según los tres diferentes valores de la columna "horas" que se pueden apreciar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tener en cuenta que **no** se conocerán los valores de la columna horas para realizar la consulta, entonces no se podrá hacer algo como `SELECT * FROM mitabla WHERE horas = "09:00 - 12:00" LIMIT 1`.

El resultado que busco es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta que busco debería detectar cuándo hay un valor igual que el anterior en la columna horas y **no** entregar los datos, sino hacerlo solo cuando se encuentre un valor distinto en dicha columna.

Podría simplemente hacer un `SELECT * FROM mitabla` y luego realizar lo que quiero en PHP, pero supongo que si logro una consulta que me traiga solo los datos necesarios, estaría haciendo un trabajo más eficiente.

De no ser posible lo que busco, muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Como defines el orden de los registros? Los registros estan ordenados por la columna `fila`?  Porque a menos que especifiques un `order by`, los registros no tienen ningun orden garantizado.

Comment: si, están ordenados por fila, pero a qué va eso?

Comment: Y digamos que hubiera un registro `fila 9`, pudiera la columna `horas` tener un valor como `09:00 - 12:00`?  O solo aperecen las horas de forma consecutiva cuando los regitros estan ordenados por `fila`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes usar el `DISTINCT` sobre el atributo horas y esto hará que te devuelva solamente las filas que tengan esa columna diferente.

```
SELECT DISTINCT horas, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado, domingo 
FROM mitabla GROUP BY horas
```

No olvides agregar el `GROUP BY` horas, para que obtengas los resultados que buscas.

Comment: Lo he probado y si aplico `SELECT DISTINCT horas FROM mitabla`, ciertamente me devuelve los datos distintos de la columna horas, pero no me devuelve el resto de los datos.
Si aplico la consulta que pusiste, obtengo todos los datos sin los criterios que busco. :s

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo Sí, disculpa, es que me faltó agregar el GROUP BY. Revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: funciona perfecto, muchas gracias!

Comment: Cuidado, que en MySQL, las columnas que no forman parte del `group by` (como las columnas `lunes, martes, miercoles, etc`) no hay garantía que salgan del primer registro. Esto es sacado de [aquí](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), donde dice en inglés: *In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are __indeterminate__, which is probably not what you want.* O sea, que los valores pueden ser aleatorios.

Comment: Lo que dice es verdad @sstan, tienes que tener cuidado con eso, pero todo depende para qué lo quieras.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo de emplear la siguiente sentencia, que es un poco más compleja, pero garantiza resultados estables para lo que estás pidiendo:

```
select t1.*
  from tbl t1
  join (select horas, min(fila) as min_fila
          from tbl
         group by horas) t2
    on t2.horas = t1.horas
   and t2.min_fila = t1.fila
 order by t1.fila
```

---

Para beneficio de otros lectores, vale la pena explicar mas en detalle por qué la otra solución propuesta no es aconsejable.

La otra sentencia propuesta es:

```
SELECT DISTINCT horas, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado, domingo 
FROM mitabla
GROUP BY horas
```

Primeramente, vale la pena mencionar que el `DISTINCT` no cumple ninguna función en esta sentencia, y se puede remover sin que afecte los resultados:

```
SELECT horas, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado, domingo 
FROM mitabla
GROUP BY horas
```

Aunque bien pudiera parecer que la sentencia resulta correcta, hay que tomar en cuenta los puntos siguientes:

1. Este tipo de sentencia, donde se incluyen columnas en el `select` que no forman parte del `group by` y que no se usan en funciones de agregación (como es el caso con las columnas `lunes`, `martes`, `miercoles`, etc), no es válido en la gran mayoría de las bases de datos populares. De modo que es bueno acostumbrarse de una vez a no escribir sentencias de esta manera.
2. Aun MySQL está dejando atrás este tipo de sentencias. A partir de MySQL 5.7.5, la configuración por defecto hace que estas sentencias sean ilegales y resultan en el error: *Expression ... of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column '...' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause*. O sea que esta misma sentencia puede que no funcione en absoluto si llegas a cambiar de base de datos MySQL. Puedes encontrar mas información a este respecto aquí: [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).
3. Aun cuando pueda *parecer* que la sentencia te da los resultados correctos, en cierta forma, se puede decir que esto es por accidente. La realidad es que no tienes ninguna garantía de que los resultados para las columnas `lunes`, `martes`, `miercoles`, etc... siempre van a ser lo que esperas. En la documentación sobre [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), allí explica como la base de datos maneja este caso:

   > In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, ***the values chosen are indeterminate***, which is probably not what you want. Furthermore, ***the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an `ORDER BY` clause***. Result set sorting occurs after values have been chosen, and `ORDER BY` does not affect which value within each group the server chooses.

   ... que traducido al español, dice mas o menos lo siguiente:

   > En este caso, el servidor puede escoger cualquier valor de cada grupo, entonces, a menos que todos los valores sean los mismos, ***los valores escogidos son indeterminados***, lo que probablemente no es lo que quieres. Es mas, ***la selección de valores para cada grupo no puede ser influenciado al agregar un `ORDER BY` a la sentencia***. Ordenar los registros ocurre después que los valores ya han sido escogidos, de modo que el `ORDER BY` no afecta cual valor el servidor escoge dentro de cada grupo.

   En otras palabras, para la hora `09:00-12:00`, no hay ninguna garantía que la sentencia va a darte los valores de la fila `1`. El servidor pudiera decidir devolverte los valores de la fila `2` or `3`, no hay manera de estar seguro. Y esto es el caso aun si le agregas un `ORDER BY` a la sentencia.