# ¿Cómo mostrar solo dos registros con id diferentes?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente tabla1:

```
nombre                       |   tipo     |   fecha      | id
-------------------------------------------------------------------
RETEN_2016_10_02_01a.txt     |    .txt    |  2016-10-02  | RETEN    
RETEN_2016_10_02_02b.txt     |    .txt    |  2016-10-02  | RETEN
RETEN_2016_10_02_03c.txt     |    .txt    |  2016-10-02  | RETEN   
STOP_2016_10_02_01a.txt      |    .txt    |  2016-10-02  | STOP         
STOP_2016_10_02_02b.txt      |    .txt    |  2016-10-02  | STOP         
STOP_2016_10_02_03c.txt      |    .txt    |  2016-10-02  | STOP
```

Tengo el siquiente query:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE fecha = '2016-10-02' and id in ('RETEN','STOP')
```

Que lo que hace es que me muestra todos los registros de esa fecha con esos id asi como lo muestro en la tabla1.

Pero como puedo lograr que solo me muestre dos registros con esos dos `id` así como a continuación lo muestro:

```
nombre                       |   tipo     |   fecha      | id
-------------------------------------------------------------------
RETEN_2016_10_02_01a.txt     |    .txt    |  2016-10-02  | RETEN     
STOP_2016_10_02_01a.txt      |    .txt    |  2016-10-02  | STOP
```

Comment: Ya probaste con la sentencia DISTINCT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: ¿Y como escoges cual registro mostrar para un `id`? Porque ninguna de las respuestas actuales te garantiza que te devuelva un registro en particular.

Comment: @sstan Realmente con mi ejemplo, tal y como comento, sacará la primera fila de ese grupo. Realmente como el OP no daba más información al respecto yo entendí que tendría que salir el primer registro de cada grupo (independientemente del registro que sea).

Comment: @Error404: Técnicamente, tu respuesta no garantiza que te devuelva el primer registro. Según la documentación de MySQL el registro que te devuelve no es definido, y pudiera cambiar sin aviso. Puedo encontrarte el enlace a esta información si lo deseas.

Comment: @Error404: Aquí te dejo un enlace a una respuesta que di hace un tiempo que explica esto en detalle: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/28634/18951

Comment: @sstan Muchas gracias por el link. La verdad que he aprendido bastante. No sé mucho de MySQL todavía así que cualquier conocimiento nuevo es bienvenido. Un saludo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es sacar la primera ocurrencia de cada grupo de `id` (la primera con el id `RETEN` y la primera con id `STOP`).

Creando el esquema de tu tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla1 (
nombre VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
tipo VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
fecha DATE,
id VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO tabla1 VALUES("RETEN_2016_10_02_01a.txt", ".txt", '2016-10-02', "RETEN");
INSERT INTO tabla1 VALUES("RETEN_2016_10_02_02b.txt", ".txt", '2016-10-02', "RETEN");
INSERT INTO tabla1 VALUES("RETEN_2016_10_02_03c.txt", ".txt", '2016-10-02', "RETEN");
INSERT INTO tabla1 VALUES("STOP_2016_10_02_01a.txt", ".txt", '2016-10-02', "STOP");
INSERT INTO tabla1 VALUES("STOP_2016_10_02_02b.txt", ".txt", '2016-10-02', "STOP");
INSERT INTO tabla1 VALUES("STOP_2016_10_02_03c.txt", ".txt", '2016-10-02', "STOP");
```

Puedes usar la sentencia `GROUP BY` al final de tu consulta sobre la columna `id`, lo cual te devolverá la primera fila de cada uno de los grupos. La consulta sería así:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE fecha = '2016-10-02' and id in ('RETEN','STOP') GROUP BY id
```

Y te devolverá la siguiente salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quieres ver la demo la puedes ver **[aquí](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/014549/3/0)**.

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada habria que saber si deseas el primer o ultimo registro en nombre, en este caso como supongo que es el primero, entonces se puede usar min() y agrupar por id:

```
select min(nombre),id from tabla1 where id in ('RETEN','STOP') group by id;

1                             |ID
-----------------------------------------
RETEN_2016_10_02_01a.txt      |RETEN
STOP_2016_10_02_01a.txt       |STOP
```

Ahora estos valores se pueden usar como llave primaria para leer el resto de las columnas:

```
select 
  a.* 
from 
  tabla1 as a,
  (select min(nombre) as nombre, id from tabla1 group by id) as b 
where 
  a.nombre=b.nombre and a.id=b.id

NOMBRE                        |TIPO      |FECHA     |ID
---------------------------------------------------------------
RETEN_2016_10_02_01a.txt      |.txt      |2016-10-02|RETEN
STOP_2016_10_02_01a.txt       |.txt      |2016-10-02|STOP
```

Comment: Aunque no es claro cual registro quiere en realidad OP, por lo menos esta respuesta garantiza resultados estables. (Nota aparte: es preferible promover el uso de la notación `JOIN ...` para juntar las tablas)

Answer (score -2):

Tal vez:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id), nombre, tipo, fecha
FROM tabla1
WHERE fecha = '2016-10-02' AND id in ('RETEN','STOP') LIMIT 2
```