# Contar los artículos escrito por cada autor con las categorías

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tengo la siguiente tabla `tbl_category` y `tbl_post`

tbl_category

```
id | name
1  | php  |
2  | ruby |
```

y tbl_post

```
id | cat |id_autor|
1  |  1  |   6    |
2  |  2  |   6    |
```

la consulta

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_post.cat,tbl_category.id,tbl_category.name, 
  COUNT(tbl_post.cat) as c 
FROM tbl_post 
INNER JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_post.cat= tbl_category.id
WHERE tbl_post.id_autor=6`
```

resultado:

```
|cat | id | name   | c |
| 85 | 85 | PHP5.0 | 5 |
```

que pasa que no me muestra el otro resultado debería mostrar la columna de ruby pero no se que estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando una función de agregación `COUNT`, mezclado junto con columnas que no forman parte de un `GROUP BY`. En otras bases de datos, esto es ilegal. Tristemente, MySQL permite este tipo de consultas, pero resulta en valores inesperados. (Puedes encontrar una explicación más detalla del porqué aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/28634/18951)

Si entiendo lo que estás tratando de hacer, esta es la consulta que necesitas (usando un `GROUP BY` con las columnas adecuadas):

```
SELECT tbl_category.id,tbl_category.name, count(*)
FROM tbl_post 
INNER JOIN tbl_category 
ON tbl_post.cat= tbl_category.id 
WHERE tbl_post.id_autor=6
group by tbl_category.id,tbl_category.name
```

[**Demostración**](http://rextester.com/FOZLO3219).

Comment: Si funciono problema resuelto muchas gracias, saludos