# MySQL - Detalle con una consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos llamada **mensajeria**, conformada por 3 tablas

> Tabla - **usuarios**

Aquí se guarda la información personal de cada usuario.

```
 ______ _________ _________ ________
| idUs | nomUs   | emailUs | codeUs |
 ────── ───────── ───────── ────────
|   1  | Andrey  | g1@d.co | 123456 |
 ────── ───────── ───────── ────────
|   2  | Paola   | g2@d.co | 123456 |
 ────── ───────── ───────── ────────
|   3  | Felipe  | g3@d.co | 123456 |
 ────── ───────── ───────── ────────
|   4  | Daniela | g4@d.co | 123456 |
 ────── ───────── ───────── ────────
```

> Tabla - **mensajes_token**

Aquí se hacen uniones de las ID de usuario que estén chateando.

Es decir que **por ejemplo**: 1.2 => **Andrey** & **Paola**

```
 ______ _____________
| idMT | Descripcion |
 ────── ─────────────
|   1  |     1.2     |
 ────── ─────────────
|   2  |     1.3     |
 ────── ─────────────
|   3  |     1.4     |
 ────── ─────────────
|   4  |     2.2     |
 ────── ─────────────
```

> Tabla - **mensajes**

Aquí se registra cada mensaje, incluyendo su TokenID para saber quién con quién conversa.

```
 ______ __________ __________ ____________ _____________________ _________
|  id  | usuarioA | usuarioB | mensaje    | date                | TokenID |
 ────── ────────── ────────── ──────────── ───────────────────── ───────── 
|   1  |     1    |     2    |   Hola     | 2017-01-17 02:52:00 |    1    |
 ────── ────────── ────────── ──────────── ───────────────────── ───────── 
|   2  |     2    |     1    |   Hi!      | 2017-01-17 02:53:00 |    1    |
 ────── ────────── ────────── ──────────── ───────────────────── ───────── 
|   3  |     1    |     2    |   Qué más  | 2017-01-17 02:54:00 |    1    |
 ────── ────────── ────────── ──────────── ───────────────────── ───────── 
|   4  |     2    |     1    | Nada, aquí | 2017-01-17 02:55:00 |    1    |
 ────── ────────── ────────── ──────────── ───────────────────── ─────────
```

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT 
   TokenID,usuarios.nomUs as destinatario,
   mensaje,
   date
FROM
   mensajes,usuarios
WHERE
   (usuarioA = ? OR usuarioB = ?) AND
   mensajes.usuarioA = usuarios.idUs AND
   usuarios.idUs <> ?
GROUP BY
   TokenID
ORDER BY
   mensajes.date DESC
```

Lo que quiero con la consulta es que, organice por fecha de forma **descendiente**, y que **NO** se repita el TokenID, como si se tratase de **DISTINCT** pero mostrando **el resto de columnas**. El uso de <> es para que el destinatario no sea "yo" sino que siempre sea el otro usuario.

Mi query no funciona como espero, no repite **TokenID** pero selecciona el primer mensaje, es decir. En vez de arrojar:

```
 _________ ________________ ____________ _____________________
| TokenID |  destinatario  |   mensaje  |        date         |
 ───────── ──────────────── ──────────── ─────────────────────
|    1    | Paola Gonzales | Nada, aquí | 2017-01-17 02:55:00 |
 ───────── ──────────────── ──────────── ─────────────────────
```

Está dando como resultado:

```
 _________ ________________ ____________ _____________________
| TokenID |  destinatario  |   mensaje  |        date         |
 ───────── ──────────────── ──────────── ─────────────────────
|    1    | Paola Gonzales |    Hola    | 2017-01-17 02:52:00 |
 ───────── ──────────────── ──────────── ─────────────────────
```

Quiero así también poder hallar los últimos mensajes del resto de usuarios.
¿Cómo puedo solucionar mi problema?

Comment: es decir que queires devolver el último mensaje entre dos usuarios, ¿verdad?

Comment: Sí, así es amigo.

Comment: ¿Vas a realizar la consulta cada vez para un usuario en particular o en general? Es decir, ¿quieres saber el último mensaje que recibió Paola, Felipe, Daniela... individualmente en cada caso o quieres extraer todos los últimos mensajes?

Comment: Hay detalles en la pregunta que no están del todo claro, por lo que no puedo darte una respuesta en buena conciencia. Pero un problema claro que tienes es que no puedes hacer un `group by` de `TokenID` y seleccionar las otras columnas sin funciones de agregación y esperar que te va a devolver los valores según tu `ORDER BY`. Para una explicación del por qué y la técnica que se necesita para resolver el problema, te refiero a esta otra respuesta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/28634/18951.

Comment: Parece que la tabla `mensajes_token` no es necesaria para la pregunta.

Comment: Para quien le interese, hice un SQL Fiddle con estos datos: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/394df8/2

Comment: @fedorqui, no me funciona tu fiddle :(

Comment: Máxima: prueba con http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/394df8, esto es, sin la parte `/2` final.

Comment: @fedorqui "Oops! Something went wrong. Try it again and if this keeps happening, email admin@sqlfiddle.com about it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según veo, lo que necesitas para el ultimo mensaje recibido es consultar directamente como dices, con un order by. sin embargo tenemos que tener en cuenta que la mejor forma para consultar esas tablas es la de determinar cual va a hacer la tabla que marque el ritmo  o principal y cual es la secundaria.

En este caso la tabla que debe ser principal es la de mensajes y la secundaria la de usuarios desde donde solo se tomará información

Para conseguir un numero determinado de mensajes solo es cuestión de cambiar ese 1 del limit por el valor que necesites

```
SELECT      MEN.tokenId 'TOKENID',
            USU.NOMUS 'DESTINATARIO',
            MEN.MENSAJE 'MENSAJE',
            MEN.DATE 'DATE'
FROM        mensajes  MEN
INNER JOIN  USUARIOS  USU
ON          MEN.USUARIOB = USU.IDUS
WHERE       (USU.IDUS = 1 OR USU.IDUS = 2)
order by    MEN.date desc limit 1
```