# intento obtener un fila determinada en MySQL pero de devuelve un valor equivocado en vez del valor que quiero que me devuelva

Tags: mysql

quisiera saber como hacer para obtener la fila remarcada en rojo porque probé con esta consulta y me devuelve el idusuario:15 y mayorpleno:2 , el problema que tengo es que no se porque me devuelve eso enves de idusuario:21

```
SELECT idusuario,count(califica) as mayorpleno FROM prediccion where califica='P' GROUP BY idusuario)
```

al hacer esta consulta obtengo la siguiente imagen:

[image: Me interesa obtener lo remarcado en rojo]

luego para obtener esa fila remarcada en roja hice esta consulta:

```
    select idusuario,max(mayorpleno) from (SELECT idusuario,count(califica) as mayorpleno FROM prediccion where califica='P' GROUP BY idusuario) as cantpleno
```

y me devuelve  idusuario:15 mayor pleno:2 cosa que no es así

[image: consulta 2]

donde está el error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que al mezclar columnas agregadas (`max(mayorpleno)`) y no-agregadas (`idisuario`) sin un `group by`, MySQL no ofrece ninguna garantía en cuanto a qué valor te va a devolver para `idusuario`. Puedes encontrar más detalles al respecto en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/28634/18951) a otra pregunta.

Para obtener el resultado que deseas, es más sencillo y correcto usar un `order by` combinado con un `limit`:

```
select idusuario, count(califica) as mayorpleno
  from prediccion
 where califica='P'
 group by idusuario
 order by mayorpleno desc
 limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Para esto debes utilizar la etiqueda HAVING

```
SELECT idusuario,count(califica) as mayorpleno 
FROM prediccion 
where califica='P' 
GROUP BY idusuario
HAVING mayorpleno = 2
```